# print the output It don`t show anything

Tags: python, dictionary

I made a dictionary in IDE and made a function to take input from user and it takes the input but when I rerun that program and try to print the output It don`t show anything. 
Here is the code, help if anyone want to.

```
# Created dictionary.

list = {}

# Made a Function to save data.

def up():
    v = int(input(f"How many inputs you want to give : "))

    for i in range(v):
        a = input(f"Give words you want to put : ")
        b = input(f"Assign : ")
        list.update({a:b})
    print(f"Saved",{a:b})


value = input(f"What you want to do ? \nSee List or update it. \nIf you want to update type 'u' , If you want to see list type 's' ")


if value == "s":
    print(list)
elif value == "u":
    up()
```

Comment: Just wondering, Why did you name a dictionary variable as list? Secondly, list is a inbuilt keyword in python, you shouldn't be using it for variable naming

Comment: Beginners mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information in your variables is stored during the execution of your script. It is not automatically carried across to *different* executions of your script. Each one is a blank slate. Even if it weren't, the first line of your program sets `list` to an empty dictionary.

At the moment, you're putting salt on your broccoli, eating it, then expecting the broccoli you eat tomorrow to *also* have salt on it.

You could serialise the dictionary to a file, that can be read back in on next execution, rather than starting with an empty dictionary each time.

Comment: You mean there is some other way to store the input data permanently in a variable.

Comment: Yeah. e.g. https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/serialization/

Comment: appreciated your help.